# Automatic logout on orientation change in Android webview app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have developed a responsive website which has login page as homepage. I have developed an android webview app for the same and its working fine.
When i login to the app everything is fine but after i rotate my mobile screen i automatically logged out and it redirects me to login page again.

please help me someone in this problem

Comment: just add config change to your activity in manifest like this.
 <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:configChanges="orientation"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, by default, activities restart on orientation change.

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to the activity declaration in your `androidmanifest.xml` to prevent the activity from restarting.

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you @Virus for your reply it worked for now.

Comment: Glad to help. do accept the answer if it served your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Every time configuration changes (screen orientation changes/ Language changes) android activity will recreate iself. This will make the screen which had components populated already get back to its initial stage. 
 Once you launch the app and login through your web view , the web view is created and you entered login credentials. now once screen orientation changes, the same web view is recreated and launched again. 
 As per your business logic, either you can lock the screen orientation change or catch the details and reuse it on configuration change. [Go through this link for details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest file
to prevent restarts when the screen orientation changes.

See this for more information : [OrientationChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)